# CSS Overlay effect on hover not working

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know why my `.cd-img-overlay` class is not working when I hover over a list item?

[**My live code here**](http://ogmda.com/sandbox/intec2/about2.php)

> CSS:

```
#cd-team .cd-img-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(92, 75, 81, 0.9);
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: .25em .25em 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
```

> HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="#0" data-type="member-1">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/bruce.jpg" alt="Team member 1" />
            <div class="cd-img-overlay"><span>View Bio</span></div>
        </figure>
        <div class="cd-member-info">
            John Smith <span>Founder &amp; President</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

I can't seem to get that overlay class to work like shown in this tutorial's demo when you hover over a team member: https://codyhouse.co/demo/side-team-member-bio/index.html

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to a site or an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: What if you try #cd-team .cd-img-overlay:hover {   ?

Comment: What Paulie_D said, try to create a minimal example.  I'd even bet that creating the minimal example will sort your issue.  That is because in my browser the CSS transition happen to `.cd-member-info` instead of `.cd-img-overlay`.  I bet you got the wrong selectors in the stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks, Paulie. Will fix and mark as closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi change the opacity for the overlay to 1 and you're there. :) It's currently set to opacity: 0 for your hover class.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a hover state to change the opacity to 1? For example:

```
a:hover .cd-img-overlay { opacity: 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code an it will work .. its just because on hover you are not changing the opacity to 1.

```
 #cd-team li:hover .cd-img-overlay {
    opacity: 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the opacity to 1 when hovering. That's why the problem is. Use the following code that is present in the working url.

```
.no-touch #cd-team li:hover .cd-img-overlay { opacity: 1; }
```